# Matching only one quotation mark

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match three cases. Two quotation marks, quotation mark on the left, and quotation mark on the right:

```
/(?<=["])(.*?)(?=["])/g // "Dialogue."
/(?<=["])(.*?)(?!["])/g // "Dialogue.
/(?<!["])(.*?)(?=["])/g // Dialogue."
```

The regexes for matching only one quotation mark aren't matching anything:

https://regexr.com/5sd5u

Why is this and, how to fix it?

Comment: What is the other boundary in case of a single quotation mark? end of word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to match three cases. Two quotation marks, quotation mark on the left, and quotation mark on the right:

You can use this simplified approach using alternation:

```sh
^(?:"[^"]*"?|[^"]*")$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iakLgj/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `"`: Match a `"`
  - `[^"]*`: Match 0 or more of any character that is not `"`
  - `"?`: Match an optional last `"`
  - `|`: OR
  - `[^"]*`: Match 0 or more of any character that is not `"`
  - `"`: Match a `"`
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `$`: End

Comment: Nice! Just one doubt: Since there is no requirement to apply some operation on the whole token (e.g. to make it optional or to multiply it etc.), the non-capturing group seems unnecessary i.e. `^"[^"\n]*"?|[^"\n]*"$` should be fine or am I missing something?

Comment: `^"[^"\n]*"?|[^"\n]*"$` is equivalent of `^"[^"\n]*"?` OR `[^"\n]*"$` where `^` is applied to first part and `$` to second part only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```js
^(?![^"](?:.*[^"])$)"?[^"]*"?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kuzoB0/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?![^"](?:.*[^"])$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if the first and last chars are not `"`
- `"?` - an optional `"`
- `[^"]*` - zero or more chars other than `"`
- `"?` - an optional `"`
- `$` - end of string.